# Measure internet connection loss time in C#

Tags: c#, performance, time, timer, network-connection

I want to check whether my internet connection is lost while my application is running and to measure the duration of any loss. For that I'm using the code below:

```
try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
            {
                //Doing something when connection running
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Doing something when connection lost
        }
```

Does anyone know how to write a log file using this code to measure my connection lost time (format: day:min:sec)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Before you put too much effort in creating a code performing something like this could you consider my [former answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179083/is-dns-lookup-a-reliable-way-to-detect-whether-a-windows-computer-is-connected-t/24184719#24184719)? I know it is a Delphi question but my answer is more logic- then syntax-related.

Comment: Actually, I want to know how much of time my application ran out of internet connection if there's a connection loss. For that matter, I'm going to create a log file storing connection loss time.

Comment: If the purpose of your application is directly logging the fact of internet connectivity, there is nothing wrong with your approach of course. In any other cases you should log if a network operation failed instead of polling for internet connectivity.

Comment: Yes, My application is directly connect with the internet. is there a way to calculate and store connection loss time into a log file? I'm looking for a code. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the internet connectivity using

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

If you want to measure the time loss then you can include timer control in your project

```
timer1.Enabled=true;
timer1.Interval=1000;
int count=0;

private void timer1_tick(object sender,Eventargs e)
{
    if(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()==false)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

This count will return you the time loss in seconds.

Comment: This works fine. but I want to convert the count into time format.

Comment: MSDN says that _"A network connection is considered to be available if any network interface is marked "up" and is not a loopback or tunnel interface."_ is it right for you? Do you want to check **network connectivity** or **internet connectivity** ?

Comment: @UserPhalcon The answer says _"This count will return you the time loss in seconds."_ What other time format do you wish for?

Comment: @mg30rg I want to check my internet Connectivity and I want the output formatted as **day:hr:min:sec**

Comment: @UserPhalcon Like `TimeSpan timeValue = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(count);` ?

Comment: @mg30rg Exactly... Thanks for helping me out. but, This gives me only upto hours of time if I'm correct. How could I get the value in date if the connection loss timer goes beyond 24hrs?

Comment: @UserPhalcon `timeValue.ToString("g");` will display `timeValue` in "hh:mm:ss.nn" format where "hh" can be more than 24.